# concatenate variables in Jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2, satellite

I'm struggling with the following example data from Satellite server when templating with Jinja2 in Ansible:

```
"results": {
    "test.example.com": {
        "interfaces": "eth0,lo",
        "ipaddress_eth0": "10.251.0.45",
        "ipaddress_lo": "127.0.0.1",
        "netmask_eth0": "255.255.255.0",
        "netmask_lo": "255.0.0.0",
        "network_eth0": "10.251.0.0",
        "network_lo": "127.0.0.0",
```

This piece of code will return: 127.0.0.1, but I want to replace 'ipaddress_lo' with the variable interface.
I've tried a million combinations... without any luck... please advice.

```
{% for items in my_host_facts.json.results %}
{% for interface in my_host_facts.json.results[items].interfaces.split(",") %}
   {{ interface }}:
        address: "{{ my_host_facts.json.results[items].ipaddress_lo }}"
        netmask: "{{ my_subnet.json.mask }}"
        network: "{{ my_subnet.json.network }}"
        gateway: "{{ my_subnet.json.gateway }}"
{% endfor %}
    dns: [ "{{ my_subnet.json.dns_primary }}", "{{ my_subnet.json.dns_secondary }}" ]
{% endfor %}
```

Kind regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `{{ my_host_facts.json.results[items]['ipaddress_'+interface] }}`.

Comment: ... if I try this the result is: ```" "```. Any thoughts? I'm trying to match string variables, which sometimes have a value of just a space or even NULL (empty field).